# How to sort individual rows in descending order?

Tags: algorithm, oracle, plsql

I have a table which looks like the following:

```
Name LastName tPoints aPoints sPoints gPoints type
John   Johnny   15      14     13      10       1
Joe     P.      12      11     26      10       1
Matt    Q.      11      26     37      44       2
Sorine  P.      55      9      8        7       2
Ali     Ahmed   30      44     88      65       2 
...     ...     ..      ..      ..     ..       3            
                                                3
```

I would like to sort INDIVIDUAL ROWS and display based on `TYPE`

NOTE: `i can't use order by in oracle because it sorts only 1 row and the others 
is sorted based on the first row`

I don't want to break the table apart into individual tables, then sort it, and then update it back to the original table.

so, the output will looks something like this, for `tPoints` - i need to display all

```
15  - John Johnny
12  - Joe P.
```

and for `aPoints`

```
44  - Ali Ahmed
26  - Matt Q.
 9  - Sorine P.
```

and so on ...

***in a nutshell, if type = 1 then sort tPoints in descending, if type = 2 then sort aPoints, if type = 3 then sort sPoints, and so on....***

what would be an efficient way to chive this?

Regards,

Comment: Row or column? Could you give us a concrete example?

Comment: just export it to excel, and rearrange it however you want.

Comment: @nathanhayfield this is a stored procedure, not possible but thanks

Comment: @Will Please take a look at the problem again, I have revised it

Comment: `display based on TYPE` How exactly `type` is involved in ordering process?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov sorry Nick Please look at the problem now, then you see how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity this example includes only two types. Add as many types as you need.

```
SQL> with t1(Name1, LastName, tPoints, aPoints, sPoints, gPoints, type1) as(
  2  select 'John'  ,  'Johnny',  15,  14,  13,  10,   1  from dual union all
  3  select 'Joe'   ,  'P.'    ,  12,  11,  26,  10,   1  from dual union all
  4  select 'Matt'  ,  'Q.'    ,  11,  26,  37,  44,   2  from dual union all
  5  select 'Sorine',  'P.'    ,  55,  9 ,  8 ,  7,    2  from dual union all
  6  select 'Ali'   ,  'Ahmed' ,  30,  44,  88,  65,   2   from dual
  7  )
  8  select type1
  9       , tpoints
 10       , apoints
 11       , name1
 12       , Lastname
 13    from t1
 14   order by case when type1=1 then tpoints else type1 end desc,
 15            case when type1=2 then apoints else type1 end desc;

     TYPE1    TPOINTS    APOINTS NAME1  LASTNAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ------ --------
         1         15         14 John   Johnny
         1         12         11 Joe    P.
         2         30         44 Ali    Ahmed
         2         11         26 Matt   Q.
         2         55          9 Sorine P.
```

Comment: This might work. Just wondering, am I going to have a problem if I want to Use the above, but `insert Into Select` into a new table, so I can display however I want - ?

Comment: @user1683987 No, you will not have any problems with the `insert into table select`. Moreover it would not make any sense to insert into a table ordered set of data.

Comment: I need to display every type individually sorted so I guess that's my only option. unless you know an other way to display -

Comment: @user1683987 Sorry, but I do not follow. What do you mean by `display every type individually sorted`? How exactly you want resulting set of data to be displayed?

Comment: I want to break space between each type and title it with something like `people with highest tPoints` then add a new line then display the data associated with that type, and so on for the other ones

Comment: let me ask you this, can I update my current table (the one i showed above) using the query you provided?